# How we can prove the irreducibility of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Suppose $A,B$ are algebraic over $F$ with minimal polynomial $f$ and $g$ respectively. Prove that $f$ is irreducible over $F(B)$ iff $g$ is irreducible over $F(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is irreducible over $F(B)$, then it is the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $F(B)$. Consequently, we have  $$[F(A,B) : F] = [F(B)(A) : F(B)] [F(B) : F] = \text{deg}(f) \text{deg}(g)$$
by the multiplicativity of the field degree and the fact that the degree of a simple field extension is just the degree of the minimal polynomial of the adjoined element. By the same argument we have $[F(A,B) : F] = [F(A)(B) : F(A)] \text{deg}(f)$ and this implies  $[F(A)(B) : F(A)] = \text{deg(g)}$. Now we can conclude that the minimal polynomial of $B$ over $F(A)$ divides $g$ and has the same degree as $g$, hence $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $B$ over $F(A)$, in particular, $g$ is irreducible over $F(A)$.